# Google App script - Cache service misses keys when using getAll method

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

In my script I'm using cache service to store big strings split into 100KB chunks. I recently discovered `getAll` method which speeds up things a lot. Unfortunately it's sometimes unreliable - it tends to miss keys when trying to load many keys at once (most often when the number of keys exceeds 200). Funny thing is that if I collect the missing keys and run `getAll` again with just the missing keys it loads all of them succesfully.

Have you ever run into similar issue? Collecting the data in a few `getAll` runs solves my problem, but I'm just curious if there are any unspecified limitations.

If anybody's interested here's my method for loading the data using `getAll`:

```
PaginatedCache.prototype._getChunksAsync = function(expectedChunkKeys) {
  var expectedChunkCount = expectedChunkKeys.length;
  var fetchedChunks = {};
  var fetchedChunkKeys = [];

  // This is done in loop, because it sometimes happens that Google cache's getAll
  // method randomly missing some keys, most often when the number of keys is greater than 200.
  // Fetching the missing keys again using getAll solves the problem.
  while (fetchedChunkKeys.length < expectedChunkCount) {
    console.log(expectedChunkCount - fetchedChunkKeys.length, 'keys need to be loaded');
    var missingKeys = this._getMissingKeys(fetchedChunkKeys, expectedChunkKeys);
    var fetchedMissingChunks = this.service.getAll(missingKeys);
    var fetchedMissingChunkKeys = Object.keys(fetchedMissingChunks);

    if (fetchedMissingChunkKeys.length === 0) {
      console.log('0 chunks loaded');
    }

    for (var missingChunkKey in fetchedMissingChunks) {
      fetchedChunks[missingChunkKey] = fetchedMissingChunks[missingChunkKey];
    }

    console.log('Loaded', fetchedMissingChunkKeys.length, 'keys');
    fetchedChunkKeys = fetchedChunkKeys.concat(fetchedMissingChunkKeys);
  }

  return fetchedChunks;
};
```

Check out also my script execution log:
[image: execution log]

EDIT: I added a simple script with reproduction: https://script.google.com/d/1-LkE70P0JJxoTqKGnoCv0mNM6wWHFAWRbFHH1SbWbnQusHuUe53cyRgn/edit?usp=sharing

Example log:

```
[18-09-01 15:17:06:396 CEST] Value length: 17888891
[18-09-01 15:17:06:409 CEST] Storing chunks test_data, Chunks: 175
[18-09-01 15:17:06:914 CEST] Chunk count in cache:175
[18-09-01 15:17:06:919 CEST] 175 keys need to be loaded
[18-09-01 15:17:07:278 CEST] Loaded 171 keys
[18-09-01 15:17:07:279 CEST] 4 keys need to be loaded
[18-09-01 15:17:07:282 CEST] Missing keys: ["test_data_PC_UNIQUE_KEY2_163","test_data_PC_UNIQUE_KEY2_167","test_data_PC_UNIQUE_KEY2_171","test_data_PC_UNIQUE_KEY2_174"]
[18-09-01 15:17:07:313 CEST] Loaded 4 keys
[18-09-01 15:17:08:510 CEST] Loaded 175 chunks from cache asynchronously
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: Have you tried reducing key string size,removing special characters?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - there are no special characters (only ascii) and the key sizes are not even the half of the limit specified here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putAll(Object)). Btw if something was wrong with the keys/values I guess that `putAll` would crash.

Comment: Possibly a similar issue as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62944260 but that Issue doesn't really convey much. If you can reproduce this reliably / package a repro instruction set, I would consider filing an issue there. My thought? `CacheService` is itself cached and with a certain volume of stored keys, you make it start missing.

Comment: Added a reproduction script to the question, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Bajena Thanks for your info about unreliable `getAll()` method! What about `putAll()` method? Can we trust it? :)